# How can I test web service (API) with Cypress with uploading a file?

Tags: cypress

Is it possible to test web service (api) with cypress with uploading a file.
I tried with cy.request, but somehow it does not recognize the file:

```
cy.fixture('exampleTsv.tsv').then((tsvExmp) => {
    const blob = Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob(tsvExmp, 'text');
    // Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob(tsvExmp).then((blob) => {
    const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('file', blob, 'exampleTsv.tsv');

    cy.request({
      url: 'APi-URL',
      method: 'POST',
      auth: {
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password',
      },
      body: {
        formdata,
      },
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'binary',
      },
    }).as('details');
    // Validate response code
    cy.get('@details').its('status').should('eq', 204);
    cy.get('@details').then((response) => {
      cy.log(JSON.stringify(response.body));
    });
  });
```

I only get: Status: 404 - Not Found. But the api-url and file is working (tested with postman: with [body->binary->tsvExmp.tsv])

Comment: cy.request seems not to work as it can't handle file.

Comment: I tried a cy.task with a fetch in it. But that will not like fetch.... (node-fetch installed)

Comment: Can't use cy.server... as it is deprecated. And cy.intercepts: i guess not for this purpse.

Answer (score 6):

The way you use alias does not wait for the response. `cy.get('@details')` is not a wait, it reads the current value.

You should use `.then()` to wait for the response (see [cy.request](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#Method-URL-and-Body))

```js
cy.request(...)
  .then(response => {
    cy.log(JSON.stringify(response.body));

    // Validate response code
    expect(response.status).to.eq(204)
  });
```

Comment: Although, maybe right, but no: this is not the problem. It fails beforehand with status: 404 - Not Found

Headers: {

  "set-cookie": [

    "JSESSIONID=7F60ECFB754AB80CA3D75D54B22ED710; Path=/Biologics; Secure; HttpOnly"

  ],

  "content-length": "0",

  "date": "Tue, 18 Apr 2023 06:01:13 GMT",

  "keep-alive": "timeout=60",

  "connection": "keep-alive",

  "server": "application-server"

}